# where is my app's acknowledgment, SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

when i use paypal SDK to my project ,the readme tell me :Add the open source license acknowledgments from acknowledgments.md to your app's acknowledgments. to config my project ,but what is where is the acknowledgment ,i have never met this when i use other SDK，

Comment: It is wherever you put it; It could a be a screen in your settings, an information screen you display somewhere else. There is no in-built "acknowledgements" screen

Comment: do u mean that i can new a group and then put the license file in to it?

Comment: Yes, that is one approach.  Here is an example using Cocoapods, but you can use any plist file you create: http://kitefaster.com/2016/01/22/how-to-add-cocoapods-acknowledgements-plist-to-ios-settings/